# In Perl, how can I find out if my file is being used as a module or run as a script?

Tags: perl, module, modulino

Let's say I have a Perl file in which there are parts I need to run only when I'm called as a script. I remember reading sometime back about including those parts in a main() method and doing a

```
main() unless(<some condition which tests if I'm being used as a module>);
```

But I forgot what the condition was. Searching Google hasn't turned out anything fruitful. Can someone point out the right place to look for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the file is invoked as a script, there will be no [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#caller) so you can use:

```
main() unless caller;
```

See [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy)'s [explanation](http://www.drdobbs.com/scripts-as-modules/184416165).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

main() unless caller;

sub main {
    my $obj = MyClass->new;
    $obj->hello;
}

package MyClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new { bless {} => shift };

sub hello { print "Hello World\n" }

no warnings 'void';
"MyClass"
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> perl MyClass.pm
Hello World
```

Using from another script:

```
C:\Temp\> cat mytest.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MyClass;

my $obj = MyClass->new;
$obj->hello;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> mytest.pl
Hello World
```

Comment: What about `perl -MMyClass -e' ... '`?

Comment: @Brad Gilber When MyClass.pm is written this way, `perl MyClass.pm` does the same thing as `perl -MMyClass -e 'main()'`

Answer (score 7):

I call these things "modulinos" originally in my [Scripts as Modules](http://www.ddj.com/web-development/184416165) article for *The Perl Journal* (now *Dr. Dobbs*). Google that term and you get the right resources. Sinan already linked to my development sources for one of my books where I talk about it. You might also like [How a Script Becomes a Module](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=396759).

Answer (score 2):

Better to not do this, and instead take a structured approach like [MooseX::Runnable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Runnable).

Your class will look like:

```
class Get::Me::Data with (MooseX::Runnable, MooseX::Getopt) {

    has 'dsn' => (
        is            => 'ro',
        isa           => 'Str',
        documentation => 'Database to connect to',
    );

    has 'database' => (
        is         => 'ro',
        traits     => ['NoGetopt'],
        lazy_build => 1,
    );

    method _build_database {
        Database->connect($self->dsn);
    }

    method get_data(Str $for_person){
        return $database->search({ person => $for_person });
    }

    method run(Str $for_person?) {
        if(!$defined $for_person){
            print "Type the person you are looking for: ";
            $for_person = <>;
            chomp $for_person;
        }

        my @data = $self->get_data($for_person);

        if(!@data){
            say "No data found for $for_person";
            return 1;
        }

        for my $data (@data){
            say $data->format;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now you have a class that can be used inside your program easily:

```
my $finder = Get::Me::Data->new( database => $dbh );
$finder->get_data('jrockway');
```

Inside an interactive script that is bigger than just the "run" method above:

```
...
my $finder = Get::Me::Data->new( dsn => 'person_database' );
$finder->run('jrockway') and die 'Failure'; # and because "0" is success
say "All done with Get::Me::Data.";
...
```

If you just want to do this standalone, you can say:

```
$ mx-run Get::Me::Data --help
Usage: mx-run ... [arguments]
    --dsn     Database to connect to

$ mx-run Get::Me::Data --dsn person_database
Type the person you are looking for: jrockway
<data>

$ mx-run Get::Me::Data --dsn person_database jrockway
<data>
```

Notice how little code you wrote, and how flexible the resulting class is.  "main if !caller" is nice, but why bother when you can do better?

(BTW, MX::Runnable has plugins; so you can easily increase the amount of debugging output you see, restart your app when the code changes, make the app persistent, run it in the profiler, etc.)

Comment: +1 for showing a Moose way. I still haven't made the investment to get into that mindset.