# When setting up Perl code to run as either a script or module, what is the reason for __PACKAGE__?

Tags: perl, module

In this [earlier Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131304/in-perl-how-can-i-find-out-if-my-file-is-being-used-as-a-module-or-run-as-a-scri) and especially [brian d foy's "How a Script Becomes a Module"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=396759) I've read about how to set up code so that it can be run as either a script or a module, using this technique:

```
package SomeModule;

__PACKAGE__->run(@ARGV) unless caller();

sub run {
    # Do stuff here if you are running the file as
    # a script rather than a module.
}
```

What is the purpose of `__PACKAGE__` in this setup? Why not just do this?

```
run(@ARGV) unless caller();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you say `__PACKAGE__->run(@ARGV)` then `run` can be defined in a class you inherit from or allows a class to inherit from this one.  If you just say `run(@ARGV)` you are missing the class information.  This only matters if you are doing OO style programming.

Put the following in a file named `Foo.pm`, and then say `perl Foo.pm 1 2 3`

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

__PACKAGE__->main(@ARGV) unless caller;

sub main {
    my $class = shift;
    my $obj   = $class->new(@ARGV);
    print $obj->to_string, "\n";
}

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless [@_], $class;
}

sub to_string {
    my $self = shift;
    return "args: " . join ", ", map { "[$_]" } @$self;
}

1;
```

Now put the following in `Bar.pm`, and say `perl Bar.pm a b c`.

```
package Bar;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Foo';

__PACKAGE__->main(@ARGV) unless caller;

sub to_string {
    my $self = shift;
    return "args: " . join ", ", map { "<$_>" } @$self;
}

1;
```

Now lets see what happens if you don't use `__PACKAGE__` in this environment.  Make the first section of code in `Foo.pm` look like this:

```
main(@ARGV) unless caller;

sub main {
    my $obj = Foo->new(@ARGV);
    print $obj->to_string, "\n";
}
```

Now run `perl Foo.pm 1 2 3`.  Everything should still look right.  Now try running `perl Bar.pm a b c`.  We still get output, but it is not the output we expect.  What happens if we remove `__PACKAGE__` from `Bar.pm`?  Well, we get and error: `Undefined subroutine &Bar::main called at Bar.pm line 8.`  This is because there is no `main` 
function in the module and we are not calling it with the class, so it won't look for it in the `Foo` package anymore.