# using files other perl files in another perl file

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I include functions from another file in my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712016/how-do-i-include-functions-from-another-file-in-my-perl-script)

I have a perl file suppose a.pl and I want to use a function from perl file b.pl. How do i do it

Comment: See similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712016/how-do-i-include-functions-from-another-file-in-my-perl-script/1712036#1712036

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180554/in-perl-is-it-better-to-use-a-module-than-to-require-a-file

Answer (score 3):

#### Turn b.pl into a module

1. Call it something descriptive like `MyBModule` (`B` is reserved by core).
2. rename the file to the something `.pm` like `MyBModule.pm`.
3. Add a package at the top, like `package MyBModule;`
4. Set a true return code on the package by making the last line `1;`

You don't have to do anything else if you want to use your package name when calling the sub.

```
use MyBModule;
use strict;
use warnings;
MyBModule::sub1();
```

If you don't want to qualify it with the package name, read on...

#### Use Exporter.pm

Now configure Exporter.

1. Add the `use Exporter;` statement at the top of your module.
2. add a line `our @EXPORT_OK = qw(sub1 sub2);`

After you're done your module should look something like this

```
package MyBModule;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(sub1 sub2);

sub sub1 { ... }
sub sub2 { ... }
```

#### Edit the caller

1. Make sure the library is in `@INC`, or the module in the current directory. If not append the directory to `PERL5LIB`.
2. Add a line like `use MyBModule qw(sub1 sub2);`

Read [perldoc Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for more information

Your script should look like this afterward:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyModuleB qw( sub1 sub2 );
```

It really isn't that hard, it takes about 15 seconds after you get used to doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The best/conventional way is to keep all your functions in a Perl module file (.pm):  See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules).  This would require you to convert b.pl to a `package`.  You would then access your module file (`MyFuncs.pm`) from a.pl with:

```
use MyFuncs;
```

Comment: You can also turn your module as modulinos, a perl module that can be called as a script - See this link for more info
http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/18.modulinos.html

Comment: @ccheneson See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131304/in-perl-how-can-i-find-out-if-my-file-is-being-used-as-a-module-or-run-as-a-scri

Answer (score 1):

Use the [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) and/or [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) functions.

Answer (score -1):

Use the 'use' keyword to use functions from another module.

Example:

File a.pl:

```
use b;
f_in_b();
```

File b.pm:

```
sub f_in_b()
{
  print "f_in_b\n";
}

1;
```

Important:
File b.pm must have the final `1;`

Comment: It isn't nearly so simple. Firstly, **never** use lowercase module names unless you're writing a pragma to change the behavoir of perl, secondly, B.pm in this example would have to have a configured `sub import {}`, this can be set up with `Exporter`, or `Sub::Install` or something, but the magic doesn't happen without that. You can still get to `f_in_b()` without it, but you have to use package-qualification, `use b; B::f_in_b();`

Comment: @Evan Carroll: I guess you are wrong: This example actually works. You don't need package qualification `B::` here.

Comment: This is something I forgot, reason being no sane person would want this. Technically what is happening is you're polluting `package main;` which is a bad thing. If you had `f_in_b()`, in the `a.pl`, the one in `b.pm` would be overwritten.

Comment: If you make a file called *.pm, it should conform to the standards of a module, unless your intent is to sabotage the code maintenance efforts of your employer or client.  Your code sets up a false expectation that b.pm will respect the `main` namespace.  You managed to trip up a skilled Perl programmer with an insane and ill-considered move.  Please read perldoc perlmod -- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html.

Comment: Yes, I know, that this example is not the official way to define a perl module. Neither did I claim that this is the case nor was it the question of manugupt1. His question was how to use a function from another perl file; nothing more. And this is probably the most minimalistic answer. I don't understand this excitement about it.