# from cron running a subroutine from a perl module

Tags: perl, cron

I have a Perl Module that i created and i want to run one of the subroutine in it on a schedule. I know I can just make a small perl script that calls the subroutine and call it from the crontab but if there is a way to call the subroutine right from the crontab that would be cool!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Perl's `-e` switch for executing code from the command line, e.g.

```
perl -e 'use your_module; your_function()'
```

Make that even shorter with the `-M` switch for loading a module:

```
perl -Myour_module -e 'your_function()'
```

The [perlrun man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the subroutine from the command line using something like

```
perl -MYour::Module=some,functions,to,import,such,as,foo -e 'foo();'
```

So you will be able to do the same from the crontab.  Note that the cron usually runs with a restricted set of environment variables, so you may need to add a `-I/path/to/your/modules` option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more elegant solution, your module can be configured to detect that it is being run as a script and behave differently in that situation.  See this discussion: [In Perl, how can I find out if my file is being used as a module or run as a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131304/in-perl-how-can-i-find-out-if-my-file-is-being-used-as-a-module-or-run-as-a-scr)